# layer.setQuery is not a function error from CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I am getting this error:

```
SELECT * FROM parcels_sa WHERE parcel_id ILIKE '%001089800%'
mapscript.js?1437514849:273
```

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: layer.setQuery is not a function(anonymous function) 
> @ mapscript.js?1437514849:273x.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5x.event.add.y.handle @ jquery.min.js:5
> cartodb.js:5 GET http://dchadney.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20ST_XMin(ST_Extent(the_geo…arcels_sa%20WHERE%20parcel_id%20ILIKE%20%27%25001089800%25%27)%20as%20subq
> ```
>
> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

[image]

```
function parcelSearch(layer) {
    var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'username' });
    var $options = $('#searchParcel');
    $options.click(function(e) {
        var streetNam = document.getElementById('parcelid').value;
        if(streetNam === "") {
            alert("Please enter the parcel ID");
        } else {
            query = "SELECT * FROM parcels_sa WHERE parcel_id ILIKE '%" + streetNam + "%'";
            console.log(query);
            layer.getSubLayer(0).show();

            sql.getBounds(query).done(function(bounds) {
                latlon = bounds[0];
               // console.log(latlon);
                //alert(latlon);
                $('.latlongit').val(latlon);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
        }

        // change the query in the layer to update the map
        layer.setQuery(query);

    });       

    var $clear = $('#clear');
    $clear.click(function(e) {
            $('#parcelid').val('');
            query = "SELECT * parcels_sa";
            console.log(query);
            layer.getSubLayer(0).hide();
            sql.getBounds(query).done(function(bounds) {
            latlon = bounds[0];
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
        // change the query in the layer to update the basemap
        layer.setQuery(query);
    });
}
```

Comment: There is an **edit** button beneath your question that allows you to revise it with the error and format it.  Comments are temporary, and only there to help you improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably needing `layer.setSQL(query)`. As the error says, setQuery is not a function in CartoDB.js.

Documentation for `setSQL` is [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sublayergetsql) and [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#sublayersetlayerdefinition).

Comment: Okay setQuery is a function in an older version of CartoDB, so that was my issue. Thanks!